# Binary math

Tags: math

If I know the number number y and know that 2^x=y, how do I compute x?

Comment: Why do you call it "Binary" math?

Comment: Because the origin of 2^ numbers is that they are essentially binary. x+1 tells me how long the binary number is (1 is 1, 2 is 2, 4 is 3, 8 is 4).

Comment: this is absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base 2 logarithm function:

```
log2(y)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
log(y) / log(2)
```

for arbitrary base.

Comment: That log trick is so handy... I was always wondering how to do arbitrary base logs on calculators.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually on to that answer but my check on the calculator told me otherwise. I then realised the calculator uses log10.

Comment: BTW, I have a question : don't you have to ensure that parameters you provide to log2 are strictly positive ?

Comment: @yves: It's a math question and it's not concerned about implementation details. log is not defined for negative numbers (not considering complex numbers, of course), so yes, you might want to validate the input in real world applications.

Comment: If we add negative numbers into the picture: http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_dft_logarithms_negative_imagina

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that it is a power of 2, then you can write a loop and right shift the number until you get a 1. The number of times the loop ran will be the value of x.

Example code:

```
int power(int num)
{
    if(0 == num)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        ++count;
        num = num >> 1;
    }while(! (num & 1) && num > 0);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, provided that x is guaranteed to be an integer of course. This *would* be the most efficient method in that case.

Comment: Most processors have built in way for doing this in a single instruction (`bsr` in x86, for instance)

Answer (score 2):

And in case you don't have a `log` function handy, you can always see how many times you must divide y by 2 before it becomes 1. (This assumes x is positive and an integer.)

Comment: Brute force approach, always good :) Probably quicker for small values of y than trying to take a log as well (optimisation anyone? 'if y < 1000000 do_division() else take_log()' :))

Comment: Funny, that. If you have a coprocessor, the threshold where the log is faster will be fairly low.

Answer (score 0):

If x is a positive integer, then, following code will be more efficient..

```
   unsigned int y; // You know the number y for which you require x..
   unsigned int x = 0; 

   while (y >>= 1) 
   {
         x++;
   }
```

x is the answer!